# Firebase Message Null - Android - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, rest

Estoy intentando enviar un mensaje de tipo `Post` utilizando `FCM`. Le paso el `Mensaje` y el `Token` pero el `response` me devuelve `nulo`. `Xamarin.Android C#.`

Estoy siguiendo esta documentación:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=es-419&fbclid=IwAR1Yv2CEdi18Hb1UhykSLtc9fKdw6n_rnz7ppum0ieNMIrU1k4mMwesDonE#c

Proceso de envio de mensaje (notificación):

```
async void SendNotification(string FCMbody, string FCMtitle)
        {
            try
            {
                // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
                var registrationToken = "MY_TOKEN";

                // See documentation on defining a message payload.
                var message = new Message()
                {
                    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "body", "body test text" },
                        { "title", "title test text" },
                    },
                    Token = registrationToken,
                };

                // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
                // registration token.
                string response = await FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
                // Response is a message ID string.
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                
            }
            
        }
```

**Error** en el message del response (flecha amarilla de imagen adjunta):

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image: Error]

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Puedes comentar el try un momento y subir el error completo? Hay varias cosas que pueden ser null

Comment: Lo hice pero me da el mismo error. -- object reference not set to an instance of an object -- No da mas detalles. Con el try al menos muestra la linea donde da el error.